# What percentage of the U.S. (Adult?) population has at some point considered suicide?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, study-cognitive-sciences

As long as the study focused on people at least 18, that's all I need. Also, the researcher's minimum requirement for 'considered suicide' must be that the person at least considered it as an option. However, his minimum requirement must not reach as high as 'attempted.'

What percentage of adults (It can be an average, or it can be specifically elderly, 30s, ... etc.) have at some point in their lives considered suicide?

Comment: Icor, could you share some initital research you have done yourself? And why are you studying this topic?

Comment: Robin, curiosity if clients might receive excessively high attention/alarm if a therapists asks and the answer is affirmative. 

Theoretical example, because people will lie to avoid taboo / stigma: The therapist doesn't know the real rate this is affirmative, because she's not familiar with research on the subject. Client is honest and answers affirmative. Therapist gives too much attention / has fear about the client's state, not realizing this is 'normal' and the majority of her clients simply lied about it... As for my research, I can't remember what I've found but nothing that answered.

Comment: Similar example: a primary care asked me if I ever have trouble separating past dreams from past real events. She didn't know the data, I did: 50% of the population has trouble with this (IIRC, per "50 Great Myths of Popular Psychology: Shattering Widespread Misconceptions about Human Behavior.") So, whether my answer was yes or no became mostly irrelevant... I'm a psych student, if that's not obvious.

Comment: "An estimated 9.3 million adults (3.9% of the adult
U.S. population) reported having suicidal thoughts in
the past year.
The percentage of adults having serious thoughts
about suicide was highest among adults aged 18 to
25 (7.4%), followed by adults aged 26 to 49 (4.0%),
then by adults aged 50 or older (2.7%)."
from https://www.cdc.gov/violenceprevention/pdf/suicide-datasheet-a.pdf

Comment: @B.Swan consider answering the question. Personally I would approve and upvote a simple cut and paste action.

Comment: I've found that, but I want lifetime rate "Some point in their lives." Thanks, though!

Comment: Could you please add these new details (context, previous research) to your question to clarify it?

Comment: Seanny123, I added details to my post - but I have no relevant previous research; the text in my OP precludes the data I've found: it would be redundant to mention it. Apart from that, did I add what you're asking for?

Comment: @icor103 If you found that very source menteiond by B Swan before (you seem to be contradicting yourself here?), this goes to show how important it is to _add sources_ to your question to further refine what exactly you are interested in, i.e., edit the question to add this reference and indicate how it _does not_ answer your question.